# call ActiveX method with return writable pointer

Tags: javascript, windows, com, activex, dcom

```
[id(0x00000002), helpstring("method ReadFromFile")]
VARIANT ReadFromFile(
            [in] BSTR FilePath,
            [out] FileStatus* status);
```

I want to call this function from ActiveX control.

but need to pass "writable pointer" to the function.

This is the question:

How could i pass a argument to function using javascript ?

Is that possible ?

Comment: What is "writable pointer"? This method takes path and returns one way data backwards filling the `status` variable.

Comment: Microsoft's Javascript COM binding doesn't support `[out]` parameters. You can still call the method, and you will get its return value (where, presumably, the actual data from the file is reported), but you can't obtain `status` value.

Comment: @RomanR. i mean the second parameter of ReadFromFile.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks. This answer close to what i wanted to do. but i can't reach to the start address of function(when debugging) because of C++ exception(e06d7363). what kind of argument should i pass to it ? any ideas ?

Comment: Try passing nothing, just calling it with one string parameter. If that doesn't work, try an empty object, `{}`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ok, both methods are not working. Maybe vbscript could possible ?. i have no idea.

Comment: You can return an object in `[out, retval]` parameter, which in turn would offer properties for data (`VARIANT`) and status (`FileStatus`).